# R: How to fill group name to data frame based on vector groups?

Tags: r

I want to add a new column to my df filled with group names (from external vectors) according to the values of another column. I don't know if its good explained, so just see the example below.

Here some example data:

```
df <- structure(list(Values = c(0, 0, 0, 129906, 0, 0, 0), code = c("217", 
"220", "221", "222", "223", "224", "225")), .Names = c("Values", 
"code"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

and the groups as vectors:

```
fruits <- c(221,222,223)
nuts <- c(220,224)
veggies <- c(217,225)
```

my expected result is:

```
  Values code  groups
1      0  217 veggies
2      0  220    nuts
3      0  221  fruits
4 129906  222  fruits
5      0  223  fruits
6      0  224    nuts
7      0  225 veggies
```

Until now I use a very complex way for this :

```
df_fruits <- df$code %in% fruits
df_veggies <- df$code %in% veggies
df_nuts <- df$code %in% nuts
df_group <- cbind(df_fruits, df_veggies, df_nuts)
df_group[,1] <- gsub('TRUE', 'fruits', df_group[,1])
df_group[,2] <- gsub('TRUE', 'veggies', df_group[,2])
df_group[,3] <- gsub('TRUE', 'nuts', df_group[,3])
df_group <- gsub('FALSE', 'NA', df_group)
df_group <- apply(df_group, 1, function(x) paste(gsub("NA", "", x), collapse = ""))
df[,"group"] <- df_group
```

Any ideas how to simplify this task? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
df$groups[df$code %in% fruits] <- 'fruits'
df$groups[df$code %in% veggies] <- 'veggies'
df$groups[df$code %in% nuts] <- 'nuts'
```

Answer (score 3):

We could do this using `merge`.  We place the `vectors` in a `list`, convert to a 2 column 'data.frame' with `stack` and then `merge` with the original dataset.

```
res <- merge(df, stack(mget(c('fruits', 'nuts', 'veggies'))),
               by.x='code', by.y='values')
names(res)[3] <- 'groups'
res
#  code Values   groups
#1  217      0 veggies
#2  220      0    nuts
#3  221      0  fruits
#4  222 129906  fruits
#5  223      0  fruits
#6  224      0    nuts
#7  225      0 veggies
```